# Streaming In Memory Word Document using OpenXML SDK w/ASP.NET results in "corrupt" document

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-word, openxml

I am unable to stream a word document that I create on the fly down to the browser. I am constantly getting a message from Microsoft Word that the document is corrupt.

When I run the code via a Console Application and take ASP.NET out of the picture, the document is generated correctly with no problems. I believe everything centers around writing the file down.

Here is my code:

```
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Create Document
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
    {
        // Add a main document part. 
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

        new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);

        Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
        body.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Hello World!"))));

        mainPart.Document.Save();
        // Stream it down to the browser

        // THIS IS PROBABLY THE CRUX OF THE MATTER <---
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=HelloWorld.docx");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word.document";
        mem.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

I have [looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307993/asp-net-open-word-document) at a lot of [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477564/why-are-docx-files-being-corrupted-when-downloading-from-an-asp-net-page) – but nothing quite works. I lot of people use `MemoryStream.WriteTo` and some use `BinaryWrite` – at this point I'm not sure what the correct way is. Also I've tried the longer content type, i.e. `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` but no luck.

Some screenshots – even if you try to recover you get the same "parts are missing or invalid"

**Solution for those who stumble on this question:**

Within the `using` directive of the `WordProcessingDocument`, you must call:

```
wordDocument.Save();
```

Also to correctly stream the `MemoryStream`, use this in the outer using block:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=HelloWorld.docx");
mem.Position = 0;
mem.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you add a wordDocument.Save(); ? I tried and the only possible code close to it is .Close() and that doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `CopyTo` instead, there is a bug in `WriteTo` which makes it fail to write the entire content of the buffer when the target stream does not support writing everything in one go.

Answer (score 3):

As variant for .NET Framework 3.5 and lower. This version of framework haven't method `CopyTo` in class `Stream`. Therefore, method `WriteTo` is replaced by next code:

```
byte[] arr = documentStream.ToArray();
fileStream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
```

Example was found by http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/04/09/creating-a-new-microsoft-word-document-from-a-template-using-openxml.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I believe your ContentType value is incorrect; that is for Word 97 - 2003 format. Change it to:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I copied and pasted your code and noticed that the :"wordDocument.close();" clausule was missing, added it and it worked (I did it in Asp.NET MVC witing an action)

Answer (score 2):

(This is using OpenXML SDK v 2.10.0 and .Net Core v2.2)

I know this has been answered but I wanted to throw out another option.  It is correct that trying to send a stream back in File() like below will result in a corrupt document:

```
                MemoryStream updateStream = new MemoryStream();
                wordDocument.Save();
                wordDocument.Clone(updateStream);


                return File(updateStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

`

A super simple alternative/workaround would be to simply convert your stream to a byte[] like below and it will result in a working word docx

```
                MemoryStream updateStream = new MemoryStream();
                wordDocument.Save();
                wordDocument.Clone(updateStream);


                return File(updateStream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Rodion's answer and match the variables used in the questions this is what worked for me:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=HelloWorld.docx");
mem.Position = 0;
byte[] arr = mem.ToArray();
Response.BinaryWrite(arr);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, always include Content-Length. If browser does not know the length of the http response body, then the connection remains opened (keep-alive). If there is no other way, save content to temp file (with delete on close option), and then get the content length.

Second, the document processing IN-MEM does not work for all options (for example, you cannot insert chunk into the document. You must use file mode).

Below is the sample for aspnet core :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<MopedResponse>> PostAsync(IFormCollection collection)
{

    string pathTemp = Path.GetTempFileName(); // get the temp file name

    // create or process the word file

    // reopen it for serving

    FileStream merged = new FileStream(pathTemp, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);

    System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = "parafa.docx",
        Inline = true  // false = prompt the user for downloading;  true = browser to try to show the file inline
    };
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", merged.Length.ToString());

    return File(merged, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "mywordFile1.docx");

}
```