# Streaming Word Doc in OpenXML SDK using ASP.NET MVC 4 gets corrupt document

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I am trying to do this on ASP.NET MVC 4:

```
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
        {
            // instantiate the members of the hierarchy
            Document doc = new Document();
            Body body = new Body();
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            Run run = new Run();
            Text text = new Text() { Text = "The OpenXML SDK rocks!" };

            // put the hierarchy together
            run.Append(text);
            para.Append(run);
            body.Append(para);
            doc.Append(body);

            //wordDoc.Close();

            ///wordDoc.Save();
        }


return File(mem.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "ABC.docx");
```

However the ABC.docx opens as corrupted and it wouldn't open even after fixing it.

Any ideas?

Linked Qs:

[Streaming In Memory Word Document using OpenXML SDK w/ASP.NET results in "corrupt" document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667513/streaming-in-memory-word-document-using-openxml-sdk-w-asp-net-results-in-corrup?lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the problem comes from missing this 2 lines:

```
wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document = doc;
```

Updated the code to below and it now works flawlessly, even without any extra flushing, etc necessary.

```
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
        {
            wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
            // instantiate the members of the hierarchy
            Document doc = new Document();
            Body body = new Body();
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            Run run = new Run();
            Text text = new Text() { Text = "The OpenXML SDK rocks!" };

            // put the hierarchy together
            run.Append(text);
            para.Append(run);
            body.Append(para);
            doc.Append(body);
            wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document = doc;
            wordDoc.Close();
        }
return File(mem.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "ABC.docx");
```